# How to interpret the bigness of a divisor over a birational variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a projective morphism between normal quasi-projective varieties, where $X$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial. A Cartier divisor $D$ on $X$ is called *$f$-big* if $D|_{X_\eta}$ is big, where $X_\eta$ is the fibre of the generic point of $Y$.

My question is: If in addition the above $f$ is birational, is every divisor on $X$ automatically $f$-big? If so, why?

BTW, The question arised when I was reading the proof of the existence of flips in [BCHM].

Comment: If $f:X\to Y$ is birational then the generic fibre is a one-point scheme ($X_\eta$ is homeomorphic to $f^{-1}(\eta)$ and the only point of X mapping to $\eta$ is the generic point $\zeta$ of $X$. Indeed if $P\in X$ maps to $\eta$, we get a map $\mathcal{O}_{Y,\eta}\to\mathcal{O}_{X,P}\to\operatorname{Frac}\mathcal{O}_{X,P}=\mathcal{O}_{X,\zeta}$, and this composition is an isomorphism by birationality, hence $P=\zeta$).

Comment: Thanks for your helpful reply! It does make sense to me now.